# Delphi 3 to SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-3

One my clients has a system written in Delphi 3 and the database is Paradox. My job is to convert it to use SQL Server 2008. How can I make it connect to SQL 2008? 
This is pretty old stuff, I know. I appreciate the help.
Thanks

Comment: If you are making such a fundamental change, then be sure to upgrade your Delphi version too. The cost in effort will be the same, but you'll gain the advantages of all the later versions of Delphi too.

Comment: It should be trivially easy to port to Delphi 2007.  Beyond 2007 you have to do the "unicode" porting changes. Moving up to 2007 makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the very least BDE should be able connect using ODBC and choosing the SQL 2008 Driver in ODBC. I haven't tried, but I doubt that the BDE SQL driver will connect to SQL 2008, and I doubt anybody will develop a BDE driver for 2k8.

Comment: ODBC is really your only choice here without a lot of re-work.

Comment: The BDE native driver (at least, the last released version of it) will support SQL 2008 if you set the compatibility mode for your database to 80 (SQL 2000) and you have a copy of ntwdblib.dll (last officially released as of SQL 2000).

Comment: Nobody should be starting to use BDE who didn't start using it before 2002.

Answer (score 1):

Do you intend on moving from Delphi 3? If so, then [SDAC (SQL Server Direct Access Components)](http://www.devart.com/sdac/) from [Devart](http://www.devart.com/) would be worth looking at. They support SQL Server 2008 but unfortunately require Delphi 5 or above. They use OLE DB and any Windows machine with 2000 or above will have the drivers installed (which is part of [Microsoft Data Access Components - MDAC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6c050fe3-c795-4b7d-b037-185d0506396c&displaylang=en)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ADO without using Ado Components, by importing ActiveX Data Objects Library, but this will require more work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not upgrade the project to Delphi 2007 as a stepping stone towards the future?  There have been many improvements and bug fixes to the language since Delphi 3 that you could easily take care of.  The pain of migration might be much easier than dealing with issues which have been already addressed and corrected in the latest versions of the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the Free Components from [Torry.net](http://Torry.net) to connect to the SQL server using ADO.

Check TaoADODataSet and Free ADO Dataset in the page http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=569. These components have Delphi 3 support.